# Setting environment variable for a Compute Engine VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, environment-variables, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, embedded-resource

I need to set an environment variable within my virtual machine on Google Compute Engine. The variable I need to set is called `"GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"`and according to Google documentation I need to set its value to the path of a json file. I have two questions:

1: Can I set this variable within the Google Compute Engine interface on GCP?

2: Can I use `System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", Resources.googlecredentials.credentials);`? Whenever I try and set this variable on my local machine I use this technique, but I set the value to the path of the file (local directory). However, because I am now using a virtual machine, I was wondering, can I set the environment variable to the actual contents of a resource file? Advantageously, this allows me to embed the credentials into the actual app itself.

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Store your credentials in a file temporarily

#### $HOME/example/g-credentials.json

```
{
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

Then upload it to your GCE projects metadata as a string

```
gcloud compute project-info add-metadata \
    --metadata-from-file g-credentials=$HOME/example/g-credentials.json
```

You can view your GCE projects metadata on the cloud console by searching for `metadata` or you can view it by using gcloud

```
gcloud compute project-info describe
```

Then set the env var/load the config in your VMs startup script

#### $HOME/example/startup.txt

```
#! /bin/bash

# gce project metadata key where the config json is stored as a string
meta_key=g-credentials
env_key=GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
config_file=/opt/g-credentials.json
env_file=/etc/profile

# command to set env variable
temp_cmd="export $env_key=$config_file"

# command to write $temp_cmd to file if $temp_cmd doesnt exist w/in it
perm_cmd="grep -q -F '$temp_cmd' $env_file || echo '$temp_cmd' >> $env_file"

# set the env var for only for the duration of this script.
# can delete this if you don't start processes at the end of
# this script that utilize the env var.
eval $temp_cmd

# set the env var permanently for any SUBSEQUENT shell logins
eval $perm_cmd

# load the config from the projects metadata
config=`curl -f http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/attributes/$meta_key -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" 2>/dev/null`

# write it to file
echo $config > $config_file

# start other processes below ...
```

#### example instance

```
gcloud compute instances create vm-1 \
    --metadata-from-file startup-script=$HOME/example/startup.txt \
    --zone=us-west1-a
```

Comment: shouldn't that `.txt` possibly be a `.sh` ??

Comment: It doesnt matter. gcloud will interpret the contents of the file as text. I specifically chose .txt so it isn't accidentally executed on the dev machine.

Comment: `chmod -x` would have about the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

you could also edit the user's profile:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

or even system-wide with `/etc/profile`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`, or `/etc/environment`

and then add:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=...
```

[Custom Metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata#custom) can also be used, which is rather `GCE` specific.

Comment: Was better if you give us complete example.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you could set it within your [RDP/SSH session](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#top_of_page).
2. No, you should set the path in the variable according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_and_providing_service_account_credentials_manually), alternatively, there are code examples that gather the service account path in a variable to use the credentials within your applications.