# How to use environment variables in Compute Engine on Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have an application running in Compute Engine on Google Cloud Platform which reads system environmental variables.

I wonder what is the way to put them in my instance so that the application will be able to read them in runtime.

Here is how I create an instance:

```
gcloud compute instances create ${PROJECT_ID} \
    --image-family debian-9 \
    --image-project debian-cloud \
    --machine-type g1-small \
    --scopes "userinfo-email,cloud-platform" \
    --metadata-from-file startup-script=${SCRIPT} \
    --metadata release-url=${BUCKET_URL} \
    --zone ${ZONE} \
    --tags http-server
```

I have some security credentials, e.g. API keys, passwords, etc. which I want to upload to my instance and expose them as env vars to be read by my application.

Is there any console available for that, flag or command to automate this?

Comment: The same way you would do it on any other computer? More seriously, could you be more precise? What OS are you using? How do you create your compute engine? ....

Comment: @night-gold on other computer I do `heroku config:set API_KEY=xxx`.

Comment: Might this be part of the answer to the question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52041092/setting-environment-variable-for-a-compute-engine-vm

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by [*connecting*](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gcloud-compute/#connecting) *over [SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys)* once you have created the instance.

It is explained in [set default values in environment variables](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gcloud-compute/#set_default_values_in_environment_variables).
For example, use the ***export command*** to set the zone and region variables like:

```
$ export CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE="us-central1-a"
$ export CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_REGION="us-central1"
```

To make these environment variables ***permanent***:

**Alternative 1: Using bashrc file**

> include these export commands in your `~/.bashrc` file

you can use nano or vim to put the variables

```
sudo nano ~/.bashrc
```

then ***restart your terminal*** and check

```
$ env
```

**Alternative 2: Using start up script**

You can also use the export command within a [*start up script*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52046997/4058484) to let your *[metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata)* to become the environment variables.

Upon creating your instance you may put it *[directly](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscriptproviding_startup_script_contents_directly)* or via a file like this:

```
gcloud compute instances create vm-1 \
    --metadata-from-file startup-script=$HOME/startup.sh \
    --zone=us-west1-a
```

If the instance is already running, follow the instructions to set a *[startup script on a running instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#startupscriptrunninginstances)* .

Please remember that if you use the method of this start up script then you will need to *[run the script manually](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#rerunthescript)* each time you set new variables.

Whatever method you choose, make sure your `$ env` setting is working correctly.
Better cek it again by ***[restarting your instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stop-start-instance)*** within *[the shell](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudshell)* or using the stop and start button in your *[console](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances)*.

Comment: What if a machine is recreated after deployment?

Comment: You can use [Instance Templates](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates/create-instance-templates). It.allows you to define the instance properties to use when creating new VM instances with identical configurations including environment variables.